# Difference rdf links and normal links

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

What is the point of linked data using rdf links. What is the difference in comparison to normal links like in web pages. In the case of rdf one rdf could have link to a different resource at a different location and that rdf could be retrieved using the dereferential URI and so on. This is exactly similar to what a crawler of web pages does. So what's new in the concept of linked data of semantic web. I mean it does that for rdf that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links as in "Linked Data" have similarity with links as in "HTML hyperlinks" but there are different two kinds of links in RDF.

First, you have the predicate links, what [RobV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107591/robv) talks about. Think about the [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) page in Stack Overflow. You have links between this page and each user's profile page:

```
so:users --> sousers:rajan-sthapit
```

Similarly, you have a link between the question you ask to your profile:

```
soq:difference-rdf-links-and-normal-links  --> sousers:rajan-sthapit
```

You can figure out what the links mean because you read English and the page text is clear enough, but an automated tool would not make any difference between those two links. With RDF, you have the predicate links that can differentiate these two situations:

```
stackoverflow.com  vocab:member  sousers:rajan-sthapit .
soq:difference-rdf-links-and-normal-links  vocab:askedBy  sousers:rajan-sthapit .
```

Here, I can even connect Stack Overflow itself to its members. I don't need to link a list to a member as the [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) page is just an artificial way of organising information. Predicate links can also relate an entity to an atomic value, like an integer or a date (which "normal links" cannot do).

Second, you have the URI links. This, as [William Greenly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611714/william-greenly) says, is not really different from URIs in the good old Web, and indeed they are used by crawlers to get a document with triples inside, index them, find more URIs, dereference them, get more triples, index them, etc. But there is more than that, due to the existence of the predicate links. As RobV mentions, a crawler or other tools can decide to look up a URI or not, based on what predicate is used. Moreover, since predicates are URIs too, RDF applications can look up those URIs and find useful information. For example, looking up `vocab:member`, I could find:

```
vocab:member  rdfs:range  foaf:Person .
```

from which I deduce, given the previous examples, that:

```
sousers:rajan-sthapit  rdf:type  foaf:Person .
```

then I can look up the URI `foaf:Person` and find:

```
foaf:Person  rdfs:subClassOf  foaf:Agent .
```

and again deduce that:

```
sousers:rajan-sthapit  rdf:type  foaf:Agent .
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between RDF links and normal links is that RDF links are strongly typed.  While standard HTML does give you mechanisms to assign a limited number of types to links (e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />`) these are all pre-defined and have narrow meanings.

RDF allows you to express links using any type you want where the type of the link can itself be defined by some vocabulary somewhere.  This is much more powerful as it allows you to express kinds of links that simply aren't possible in HTML alone.

In terms of crawlers this allows you to write more intelligent crawlers that only follow the types of links you actually care about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no different between Semantic Web URI's and current Web URI's, save that URI's used in a webpage are generally constrained to the vocabulary defined as part of the HTML standard. Having said that, RDFa and other things such as Microdata, allow you to extend that vocabulary of terms.

If you are more concerned about comparing the Web to the Semantic Web, then the different is that the Semantic Web is more about data that you find in databases. It just so happens that RDF is the way of representing that data (you wouldn't use HTML to represent it, rather to present it in a human readable format).